# Is there a way to ignore a potentially hanging function call?

Tags: .net, freeze

I have a program that uses automation and gets objects from the running object table.  I notice that very rarely I end up in a state where all of my automation stops working (I automate Excel, word, Visual studio ).  I'm doing voice commands using dragon naturally speaking.

Occassionaly, I can end up in a state where EXCEL is hung. (not responding in task manager).

Dragon crashed earlier, which may have had something to do with it.

The call to runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers(0), runningObjectVal) seems to hang.

Now I don't really care that much that EXCEL is hung, but my code that loops through all of the objects in the running object table hangs, and this stops any of my voice commands from working in Visual Studio.

**Is there any way you would recommend for doing a call to this function with a time out (probably on a separate thread)?**

The annoying part is that this happens very infrequently, I don't get a crash or an error message (all of my commands run in separate threads so other types of commands keep working).  I start closing down visual studio windows and sometimes restart the computer.

Just killing excel fixes the problem (if I can remember to do that).

Comment: This is the inevitable price of interop.  You not only import the functionality of another program, you import its bugs as well.  Running code on another thread doesn't help, COM marshals it back.  The IMessageFilter interface was designed to deal with hanging interop calls but it is pretty unlikely that will do anything if it hangs on the ROT.  Uninstall buggy programs that make your life miserable.

Comment: I'm not sure separate thread will help but occasionally if Word and Excel are hidden and attempt to prompt the user with some message the automation appears to hang. If you're using Excel and the instance you're using is hidden make it visible and see if there are any popups. There are some options in the API to prevent most popups